React native + expo: Run android app in Emulator error debugging
I am trying to run a react native android app in the emulator like this:
./gradlew clean assembleDebug under the android directory. After that, I manually install the app in the emulator by executing this command: adb -s emulator-1234 install android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Why like this instead of npx react-native run-android --deviceId emulator-1234? Because it hangs up with 99% Executing -> :app:installDebug. I don't know why, but that's why I do it manually.
However, upon launching the installed apk in the emulator, I get the error below:
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): This error is located at:
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in r
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in PanGestureHandler
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in n
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in p
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in y
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RNCSafeAreaProvider
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in p
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RNGestureHandlerRootView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in n
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in n
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in j
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in RCTView
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in Unknown
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):     in l, js engine: hermes, stack:
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): qi@315:92079
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): e@315:41155
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): Dl@315:53857
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): Ma@315:95383
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): zi@315:86080
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): Ri@315:86008
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): Pi@315:85773
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): ki@315:82742
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): xt@315:27347
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): hi@315:79732
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): nu@315:94399
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): anonymous@315:100628
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): anonymous@78:542
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): anonymous@267:814
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): anonymous@258:1452
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): runApplication@258:2464
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): value@82:3903
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): anonymous@82:761
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): value@82:2590
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534): value@82:732
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:149)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:234)
08-25 21:56:02.192 E/unknown:ReactNative( 7534):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
08-25 21:56:02.200 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter( 7534): Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10203; state: ENABLED
08-25 21:56:02.214 D/Auth    ( 7534): instance-destroyed
08-25 21:56:02.215 I/ExpoModulesCore( 7534): ✅ ModuleRegistry was destroyed
08-25 21:56:02.216 I/ExpoModulesCore( 7534): ✅ AppContext was destroyed
08-25 21:56:02.216 I/ExpoModulesCore( 7534): ✅ KotlinInteropModuleRegistry was destroyed
08-25 21:56:02.219 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater( 7534): Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager

With such a crap of stacktrace, how can I find what is the cause of the exception? Any help on how to properly test this app in an emulator will be greatly appreciated.
I am new to react native dev.
My dev env is windows with WSL2. Managed to launch a new device with avd from wsl and it is detected without issues, even when the Android SDK was installed in windows.
Thanks!
